# how to pass the view id to the CJuiDialog box?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

here's my code

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',array(
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
          'name' => 'emailaddress',
          'htmlOptions' => array(
            'width' => '30',  
          ),
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'secretkey',
          'htmlOptions' => array(
            'width' => '40px',  
          ),
        ),
        array(
          'header' => 'Options',
          'class' => 'CButtonColumn',  
          'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}',
        ),
        array(
          'header' => 'Copy URLs',
          'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
          'template' => '{copy}',
          'buttons' => array(
            'copy' => array(
                'label' => 'copy url',
                'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("emails/view",array("id"=>$data["emailid"]))',
                'options' => array('id' => $data["emailid"]),
                'click' => 'function(){$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;}',
            )  
          ),
      ),
    ),
));

?>

<?php
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
   'id' => 'mydialog',
   'options' => array(
     'title' => 'URL + Key',
     'autoOpen' => false,
     'width' => 500,
     'height' => 300,
   ),
));


//THIS PART SHOULD RECEIVE THE ID SO THAT I CAN QUERY TO THE DB TABLE

?>

<?php
$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
?>
```

my question is, how will i pass the ID of the clicked row, to the Dialog box? , so that I can use that ID in order to render the correct contents inside the dialog box ?
because with the help of that ID, i can do a db query like this

```
SELECT u.url,e.secretKey FROM tbl_emails AS e, tbl_urls AS u
WHERE emailid = ID;
```

Comment: hey, is the code above working? i just tried it and it wasn't working, namely `'options' => array('id' => $data["emailid"]),` , this line is giving a PHP error, saying "Undefined variable: data", so i don't think you can access the data for the row inside the options.

Comment: CJuiDialog usually works by binding to a known link (or something) which already has the ID, not by being called from somewhere else and having the ID passed to it. It might be tough to get it to work this way...

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery data method.
For example:

```php
<?php
...
'copy' => array(
    'label' => 'copy url',
    'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("emails/view",array("id"=>$data["emailid"]))',
    'options' => array('id' => $data["emailid"]),
    'click' => 'function(){$("#mydialog").data("emailid",$(this).attr("id")).dialog("open"); return false;}',
)
...
?>
<?php
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
   'id' => 'mydialog',
   'options' => array(
     'title' => 'URL + Key',
     'autoOpen' => false,
     'width' => 500,
     'height' => 300,
     'close'=>"js:function(){
            $('#mydialog').removeData('emailid');
        }",
   ),
));

// GETTING THE ID
?>
$('#mydialog').data('emailid');

<?php
$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
?>
```